# using Shift + Enter key to run a function

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I'm kind of new to JS, I have searched the internet and I haven't got what I'm looking for, I want to run a function if the keys Shift and Enter were pressed, like a shortcut,
I have tried this but I think I killed JS with this code

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' + 'Shift') {

       console.log("test");
    }
});
```

anything would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `e.shiftKey` to see if shift is being pressed.

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.shiftKey) {
    console.log("test");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty expandable solution because you can create shortcuts for many different keys.

```js
const keysDown = {};
document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ key }) => {
  keysDown[key] = true;
  if (keysDown.Shift && keysDown.Enter) console.log("test");
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', ({ key }) => {
  keysDown[key] = false;
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, this is exactly what I need, really appreciate it.